# Should I change the pointer to an array?

Tags: c, malloc, buffer, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
for (int a=0; a<10; ++a) {
    printf ("%d", a);
}

char *foo;
foo = (char*)malloc(a);
```

I want to store more than one `char` value in `foo` variable.

> Should I change it to an array, since the buffer is only allocating 1 `char` length?
>    Is 1 the longest length that can be stored in this buffer?

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to save more than one foo variable" ?

Comment: @Magix I meant store, sorry. I fixed it

Comment: Please read the man page of `malloc()`.

Comment: Note: Don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C.

Comment: There are good reasons a _pointer_ is not called "array" and vice-versa.

Comment: If one of the answers solved your question, you should [mark it as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Well, foo now points to some useable address of `a` bytes, because this is how `malloc()` works. It doesn't matter if its type is `char *`, `void *` or anything else, you can only use `a` bytes.

Here, you increment `a` to 10. That means you can store 10 bytes, being 10 `char`s, (because in the context of C, 1 char = 1 byte), starting at the address where `foo` points to. Using a pointer or an array is strictly equivalent.

Comment: i get it now. Thanks @Magix

Comment: So my longest printable is 10 bytes, since I have allocated 10 bytes. Anything more will cause a buffer overflow, correct?

Comment: Yes, absolutely correct. Writing more to the allocated space will result in a buffer overflow and can lead to a segmentation fault.

Comment: Nit: 1 char = 1 byte *always*. In the context of C, "byte" and "char" are synonymous. This is not system-dependent.

Answer (score 1):

> *Since the buffer is only allocating 1 char length...*

No, it is not the case here.

Quoting from the `C11` standard, chapter §7.22.3.4, *The `malloc` function*

> `void *malloc(size_t size);`
>
> The `malloc` function allocates space for an object whose size is specified by `size` and
>   whose value is indeterminate.

So, in case of

```
foo = malloc(a); //yes, the cast is not required
```

a memory of size same as the value of `a` will be allocated, considering `malloc()` is successful.

Simply put, if I write a snippet like

```
 int * p = malloc(10 * sizeof*p);
```

then, I can also write

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 10, i++)
     p[i] = i;
```

because, I have allocated the required memory for 10 `int`s.

That said, [please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: since the vaule of a is 10. I can safely store 10 bytes if malloc() is successful?

Comment: @suitedupvet83 In this case, yes, you certainly can. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you could do in a case like this.

1. If you know at compile time how many chars you want to store you could make it an array `char foo[10];` If you know that there is always going to be 10 (or less) characters you want to store.
2. If you are not sure how many chars it needs to hold at compile time you would typically do dynamic allocation of memory using `malloc`. Now when using malloc you specify how many bytes of memory you want so for 12 chars you would do `malloc(12)` or `malloc(12 * sizeof(char))`. When using malloc you need to manually `free` the memory when you are done using it so the benefit of being able to ask for arbitrary (within limits) sizes of memory comes at the cost of making memory management harder.

As a side note: You typically do not want to cast the return value of `malloc` since it can hide some types of bugs and `void *`, that `malloc` returns can be implicitly cast to any pointer type anyway.